# How to add custom column in DHTMLX grid version 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtmlx

```
   function BindDataToGrid() {
            var grid = new dhx.Grid("grid_container", {
                columns: [
                    { width: 150, id: "ProductCode", header: [{ text: "<span class='title'>Product Code</span>" }] },
                    { width: 200, id: "ProductName", header: [{ text: "Product Name" }] },
                    { width: 200, id: "ProductManufacturedDate", header: [{ text: "Manufacturing Date" }] },
                    { width: 150, id: "ProductPrice", header: [{ text: "Price" }] },
                    //Add custom column here for edit and delete purpose   
                ],
                headerRowHeight: 50,
                width: 800,
                height: 400,
                data: dataset,
                resizable: true
            });
        }
```

i want custom columns after product price column.
Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

For the custom displaying content in the grid column you may try to use the template for the grid column. As in the following sample:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/suite/samples/grid/02_configuration/02_cell_templates.html